# Change verbose name and help text on Django Admin Page

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, psycopg2

i'm developing a django site deployed via Nginx and PostgreSQL.
I did some changes to my models.py and admin.py pages to correct a field.
Yet this change is not being shown in my Django admin page, it's still with the old field names regardless of the change in my models.py folder.[image: Django Admin Page]

Here's the models.py and admin.py sections of code
models.py

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Titulo del Proyecto", verbose_name="Titulo")
subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Subtitulo", verbose_name="Subtitulo")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images',blank=True, help_text="Imagen del Proyecto", verbose_name="Imagen")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, help_text="No tocar", verbose_name="Slug")
description = models.TextField(help_text="Descripcion del Proyecto", verbose_name="Descripcion")
date = models.DateField()
video_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,help_text='Url del video ', verbose_name='Video URL')
source = models.ForeignKey('Source', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, help_text='Youtube o Vimeo o NONE si no hay video',verbose_name='Source')
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text='Categoria del projecto', verbose_name='Categoria')
```

admin.py

```
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
pass
list_display = ('title', 'date', 'category', 'source')
list_filter = ('date', 'category', 'source')
search_fields = ('title', 'description')
ordering = ['-date', 'title']
date_hierarchy = 'date'
fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('title','subtitle', 'description', 'image', 'date', 'video_url',  'source', 'category', 'slug')
    }),
)
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check you question, your code is not completely there, or it from different project: for example, label in model for category is  "Categoria", field label on the admin panel is "Catégorle".

I can imagine, that you work with lazy translations. In this case you should change translations for 'label' and 'help_text' and not to do something with models.

Other case is, you Admin form is overridden. There you can change labels and help text too.

Comment: this is the exact reason why i'm asking the question, i first wrote them in french, then got asked to change it to spanish so i edited my models.py and the changes do not appear in admin.
i did change the translations as you can see in category it says" help_text='Categoria del projecto', verbose_name='Categoria')" it's already changed properly to spanish but it wont change